# Incorrect serialisation of DateTime offset in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I'm having an issue with DateTimeOffset being parsed by MVC controller that is incorrectly setting it to "+00:00" vs "+10:00". The strange thing is when I run it locally there is no issue, however when it gets deployed to a container in azure the issue presents itself. Its like the serilization process is different locally vs in the container. I'm lost to what the issue could be.

My development machine is MacOS using an Intel processor.
The container is deployed to Azure AKS.

In my Startup file I have:

```
  services
            .AddControllers(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = true; })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
                options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind;
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
            });
```

Model:

```
 public class OpeningHours
{
    public DateTime Opens { get; init; }
    public DateTime Closes { get; init; }
}
```

incorrect response:

```
  {
      "opens": "2022-11-22T11:00:00+00:00",
      "closes": "2022-11-22T23:30:00+00:00",
    }
```

Correct response (when run locally):

```
{
  "opens": "2022-11-22T11:00:00+10:00",
  "closes": "2022-11-22T23:30:00+10:00",
}
```

Any Suggestions on what could be causing it? Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example data and maybe the model class you are using?

Comment: Please make sure, that your Azure account have the correct timezone set.

Comment: Updated with class and data returned

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak why would the timezone be important for preserving the timezoneoffset?

Comment: DateTime has no Offset. Have you tried [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: ^^ If you run locally it will just use your machine's TimeZone. But you wouldn't want that in production. You need the clients' offsets.

Comment: If you wish to display time to the client in local time then you will need to harvest their location/time zone somehow and use that to adjust any time that you pass back for display. All server times should be in UTC as this will make it easier to adjust for client local time.

Comment: I have the timezone info available, and the offset exist against the DateTime I was just trying  to understand why the serilization process was removing the offset. Might just try changing the API models to DateTimeOffSet to resolve the issue.